# Hadoop mapreduce using 2 mapper and 1 reducer using c++

Tags: c++, hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-partitioning

Following the instructions on [this link](http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_2.2_--Running_C%2B%2B_Programs_on_Hadoop), I implemented a wordcount program in c++ using single mapper and single reducer. Now I need to use two mappers and one reducer for the same problem.

Can someone help me please in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

The number of mappers depends on the number of input splits created. The number of input splits depends on the size of the input, the size of a block, the number of input files (each input file creates at least one input split), whether the input files are splittable or not, etc. See also [this post in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591278/hadoop-mapreduce-default-number-of-mappers).

You can set the number of reducers to as many as you wish. I guess in hadoop pipes you can do this by setting the `-D mapred.reduce.tasks=...` when running hadoop. See [this post in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885441/setting-the-number-of-map-tasks-and-reduce-tasks).

If you want to quickly test how your program works with more than one mappers, you can simply put a new file in your input path. This will make hadoop create another input split and thus another map task.

PS: The link that you provide is not reachable.